# how to know on my linux machine if connection VIA sftp is active

Tags: linux, ftp, sftp, protocols

I have Linux machine red-hat 5.X

please advice - which what command I can identify if someone is tiring to
copy files from my machine VIA sftp or ftp
is it possible to verify this on my Linux machine ?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can use `lsof` to see what activity is currently taking place on the server. Here's what the output would look like for an idle connection to an SFTP server.

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/lsof -p $(pgrep sftp)
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
sftp-serv 30268  sam  cwd    DIR       0,19    20480  28312529 /home/sam (mulder:/export/raid1/home/sam)
sftp-serv 30268  sam  rtd    DIR      253,0     4096         2 /
sftp-serv 30268  sam  txt    REG      253,0    51496  48727430 /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0   109740  46368404 /lib/libnsl-2.5.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0   613716  48382913 /usr/lib/libkrb5.so.3.3
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0  1205988  48387619 /usr/lib/libnss3.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0    33968  48377969 /usr/lib/libkrb5support.so.0.1
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0    15556  48387614 /usr/lib/libplc4.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0    11524  48387615 /usr/lib/libplds4.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0   190712  48383685 /usr/lib/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0  1706232  46368382 /lib/libc-2.5.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0    50848  46367899 /lib/libnss_files-2.5.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0    46624  46367905 /lib/libnss_nis-2.5.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0  1298276  46368392 /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0   232156  48387613 /usr/lib/libnspr4.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0    45432  46368394 /lib/libcrypt-2.5.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0   121324  48387616 /usr/lib/libnssutil3.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0    75088  46368385 /lib/libz.so.1.2.3
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0   137944  46368395 /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0    15308  46368401 /lib/libutil-2.5.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0    20668  46368384 /lib/libdl-2.5.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0   130860  46368381 /lib/ld-2.5.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0   157336  48382170 /usr/lib/libk5crypto.so.3.1
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0    93508  46368390 /lib/libselinux.so.1
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0   233296  46368389 /lib/libsepol.so.1
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0     7812  46368391 /lib/libcom_err.so.2.1
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0    84904  46368388 /lib/libresolv-2.5.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam  mem    REG      253,0     7880  46368387 /lib/libkeyutils-1.2.so
sftp-serv 30268  sam    0u  unix 0xcb014040      0t0 104100868 socket
sftp-serv 30268  sam    1u  unix 0xcb014040      0t0 104100868 socket
sftp-serv 30268  sam    2u  unix 0xd8077580      0t0 104100870 socket
sftp-serv 30268  sam    3u  unix 0xcb014040      0t0 104100868 socket
sftp-serv 30268  sam    4u  unix 0xcb014040      0t0 104100868 socket
```

Now when some files are currently being copied from the server:

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/lsof -p $(pgrep sftp)
COMMAND     PID USER   FD   TYPE     DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME
sftp-serv 30268  sam  cwd    DIR       0,19    20480  28312529 /home/sam (mulder:/export/raid1/home/sam)
...
sftp-serv 30268  sam    5r   REG       0,19  3955027   9257067 /home/sam/which witch is wich-dDSr2oxZeAM.mp3 (mulder:/export/raid1/home/sam)
```

The line that shows me copying the file `which witch is wich-dDSr2oxZeAM.mp3` is at the bottom of the output.

When I use SFTP to `put` a file it shows up like this:

```
sftp-serv 30268  sam    5r   REG       0,19  1933312   9257073 /home/sam/bob.mp3 (mulder:/export/raid1/home/sam)
```

See a difference?

Me neither, so this method can only tell you whether a file is  currently being accessed via a `put` or `get` but it cannot distinguish between the two. However this will tell you if the connection is "active" in the sense if there's a file being read/written from/to the SFTP server.

#### Watching the daemon

I typically use this method when I want to watch the SFTP server.

```
$ sudo watch "/usr/sbin/lsof -p $(pgrep sftp)"
```

This will run the `lsof` command every 2 seconds, "polling" it for any activity.

#### Multiple connections

If you have more than 1 user connecting at a time, you may need to modify the `$(pgrep sftp)` and pick a specific PID, if there are multiple `sftp-server` instances. Also you'll have to identify which user is accessing the files via SFTP. For that though, you can look at the "USER" column in the `lsof` output.